# Updating wheezy breaks Adafruit_CharLCD

Tags: raspbian, python, output, raspbian-wheezy

So, just to try and keep the wheezy up to date I did an `apt-get dist-upgrade` and upgraded a couple of things, among which python.

Now, when I try runing the example `./Adafruit_CharLCD.py` I get no output to my mini LCD screen, which before the update all was going great.

I don't get any kind of error besides the same one as before

```
./Adafruit_CharLCD.py:68: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway. Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) ....
```

Any ideas what could go wrong, or any way of debugging why doesn't it output nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the `Adafruit_CharLCD.py` file, where having the following line

```
def __init__(self, pin_rs=25, pin_e=24, pin_db=[23,17,21, 22], GPIO = None):
```

which in the previous version (note that this was the first time that I ever started working with RaspberryPi, and, Adafruit LCD) the `pin_db` set, by another person, to `[23, 17, 27, 22]`

more details here: http://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/python-code